# Derived subgroup of the connected component of an algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $G$ be an affine  group variety (smooth) over a field $k$, let $G^0$ be the connected component of $G$.

- Is it true that the derived subgroup $[G^0,G^0]$ (Or $[G,G^0]$) is the connected component of $[G,G]$? If not, in which cases is this true? ($G$ reductive?)
- Since $G^0$ is irreducible we can construct $[G^0,G^0]$ as the schematic image of the map $${G^0}^{2n}\longrightarrow G^0; \;\;\; (g_1,g_1',\ldots,g_n,g_n')\mapsto [g_1,g_1']\cdots[g_n,g_n']$$ 
  for $n$ large enough. Does the same hold for $G$ instead $G^0$? I think that the previous point would imply this one.
- Finally, does this hold for general smooth group schemes over $k$ or over more general rings?

Edit: this is Proposition 6.20 of Milne's book of algebraic groups.

Comment: There are easy 1-dimensional counterexamples to the first question (say, with $G^0$ abelian).

Comment: The second question has a positive answer (I don't see any serious use of irreducibility).

Comment: @YCor I'll try to think about the counterexample. With respect to the second one,  I don't see the argument, could you please explain it? I would be very grateful.

Comment: (We can enlarge the ground algebraically closed field to be uncountable, so a variety can't be proper union of a sequence of constructible subsets) Let $H$ be the derived subgroup and $H_n$ be the set of products of $n$ commutators; since $H=\bigcup_n H_n$ we are done. The whole point is the basic theorem that the derived subgroup is an algebraic subgroup.

Comment: But that works if we suppose that all the points of the derived subgroup are in fact products of commutators. Maybe I should write in the question that (following Milne's book of algebraic groups) I define the derived subgroup as the closure of the union you did (this is the smallest algebraic  subgroup with abelian quotient). Then I would like to prove that the commutator is the closure of one of the $H_n$ (that’s why with irreducibility is easy).

Comment: Yes, this is the case (the derived subgroup **is** the set of products of commutators and is closed). See Chap 1, §2 in Borel's book. Actually Borel's Proposition 2.2 even says (with much more general assumptions) explicitly that there exists $n$ such that every product of commutators is product of $n$ commutators. This applies more generally, for irreducible varieties $V_i$ and morphisms $f_i:V_i\to G$ whose image contains $1$ for each $i$, to the subgroup generated by $\bigcup f_i(V_i)$.